# at line no 21 tony is coming as a string i want a variable tony . tell

Tags: javascript, arrays

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmaLH.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzk2l.png)
i simply want "  n " in the result. at line no 21 they are treating tony as string but i want them to treat tony as variable .

```
let alpha = [
    {Pune:"n",Mumbai:"m"},
];
const hulk = alpha[0];
const tony = "Pune";
***const iron = hulk.tony;***
console.log(iron);
```

this is my code , at const iron .
please solve this

.